# Assign Category Values according to wildcards in assignment table

Tags: vlookup, openoffice-calc

I am having trouble assigning category Values in a table according to wildcards in another table. There seem to be no function in calc that would help me to solve this problem.

Example:

**Data Table** (bold values in the category column are inserted by a function)

| Sentence | Category |
| --- | --- |
| This is an BMW model | **Car** |
| This Phillips is for the kitchen | **Kitchen applience** |
| This is Synology device | NA |

**Assignment Table**

| Search Term | Category |
| --- | --- |
| BMW model | Car |
| Phillips | Kitchen applience |
| * | NA |

So what I want to achieve is similar to VLOOKUP but the search term (lookup value) and the text must be in the opposite tables.

Is this achievable with only calc functions or do I need a macro for that?

Any help, hints or links to existing solution is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**: Those tables are on a separate Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume "This is an BMW model" is in cell `A2` and "BMW model" is in cell `C2`. Enter the following formula in cell `B2` and drag to fill down.

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("R"&SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:A2;"*"&C$2:C$3&"*")*ROW(D$2:D$3))&"C"&COLUMN(D1);0);"NA")
```

Result:

```
Car
Kitchen applience
NA
```

Breakdown:

- `IFERROR(...;"NA")` - If no matches are found, then the row will be 0, causing `INDIRECT` to give an error.
- `INDIRECT("R"&...)&"C"&COLUMN(D1);0)` - Using R1C1 notation, get the value of the cell in the category column.
- `SUMPRODUCT(...)` - Get the results of array calculations and combine them into a single value.
- `COUNTIF(A2:A2;"*"&C$2:C$3&"*")*ROW(D$2:D$3)` - Here is the core of our formula. If `A2` matches a regular expression such as `"*" & C2 & "*"` then mutiply it by an array containing the row number. So a match will multiply 1 by the row number of the search term, while the other row numbers will be multiplied by 0 and therefore ignored in the final sum from `SUMPRODUCT`.

If multiple matches in one sentence are possible, then the formula would need to be modified to handle that.

Comment: Hi Jim, amazing formula, I changed the formula so that the */NA are on the top so additional Categories can be added later on. I would need those tables to be on the separate sheets so that data is separate from the lookup table, is that possible? I tried with the following version but is doesnt work: `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet2.R"&SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:A2,"*"&$Sheet2.B$3:B$6&"*")*ROW($Sheet2.C$3:C$6))&"C"&COLUMN($Sheet2.C2),0),"NA")`

Comment: This works for another sheet: `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet2!R"&SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:A2;"*"&$Sheet2.B$3:B$6&"*")*ROW($Sheet2.C$3:C$6))&"C"&COLUMN($Sheet2.C4);0);"NA")`. I didn't check closely, but it looks like the reason yours didn't work is that `!` is required for `INDIRECT`. Also remove the `*/NA` row, because it is not needed and also  "***" will match everything, causing multiple matches, which will fail. Be sure that all four rows (3 to 6 on Sheet2) are filled, or else it will fail.